How to run command automatically when hit Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)?
I am trying to perform long-term reboot debugging on a system, but the system randomly encounters some Break instruction exceptions that pause my tests. Unfortunately, the code for this Break instruction exception is 80000003, which is the same as the issue I am trying to debug, so I cannot directly ignore it using the event filter. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is any command to determine if a Break instruction exception is caused by a specific address and, if so, to let it continue execution automatically.
Below is one of the Break instruction exceptions, and the address encountered each time is a fixed value:
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
nt!ExpWaitForResource+0x2eb200:
fffff907`ace9974b cc              int     3

I tried using
bu nt!ExpWaitForResource+0x2eb200 "g"

and
bp nt!ExpWaitForResource+0x2eb200 "g"

commands, but they did not actually execute the g command.

What about sxe -c "g" for bpi, bpe and bpec?

Maybe related: Why does the new windbg clear my breakpoints after .reboot

sxe -c "g" will release all Break instruction exception - code 80000003, so it will not break when my bug hit the break. And I already save my bp to workspace and make sure break point is still exist after reboot.

Okay, understood.

Have you tried fix the reason for the exception?
Anyway... You can try handle with a try/catch like this:
    __try {
        // Your code that might trigger the exception
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == 0x80000003) {
        // Handle the breakpoint exception (code 80000003)
        // Run your custom code here
    }

I hope this helps!

So you have access to the source code of ntdll.dll, i.e. Microsoft code and just fix it? Please clarify if I misunderstood. OP's breakpoint is in nt!something.

Have you read the fix?

And how is the linked question relevant to this? The linked question is about fixing the symbols.

It is the reason for 0x80000003 exception!

Thanks, these break are not caused by my code, and nothing happened after I let it go. I just need a method to skip it if it's caused by nt!ExpWaitForResource+0x2eb200, so my test can keep going and might hit the real issue I'm tracking.
